# Parental control of screentime on webOS-based smart TV using (Samsung) Android phone

Tags: smart-tv, parental-control

I've got an LG Smart TV (webOS - not Android), hardwired to the router and I have a Samsung Galaxy A54 phone.  What I thought would be a straightforward IoT service to allow you to set/pause internet-screentime of the LG SmartTV, ideally from anywhere, using the phone, appears difficult/impossible. In summary, this is what I have tried.

1. Using the router settings (access via 192.168.1.1). This provided very crude settings of time limits in blocks of 1 hour, that can be applied to the SmartTV-internet connection.  When I set these times, they worked somewhat randomly (not triggering at the exact set times or not triggering at all).  Also, there is no app for the phone, and access is only while using the network and using a web portal (e.g. Chrome/Edge) while on the network.
2. Googling this question mostly brings up links to Parental Control of Android devices (LG is webOS-based).  I tried to use the Android Parental Control app on my phone.  It appears the app wants to pair with a device that has the app installed.  However, the LG webOS is not Android-compatible.
3. Looked for apps on the LG webOS shop to control the internet connection.  This did not provide any obvious solutions.

I've run out of ideas.  Is there any solution (hardware, software, or combination) where I can control the screen time of Internet TV?

[I am happy to consider using a hardware item (e.g. Chromecast) to put between the router and the TV if such a solution is available/possible]

Comment: I'm sorry, this question is off-topic on this SE.  You may want to try Hardware Recommendations SE or Software Recommendations SE, but it will be a bit tricky as there is no "Hardware or Software Recommendations SE".  Perhaps with a little editing, you can post a topic-specific version of your question on each.  I hope you find good answers to your question.

Comment: I think this question has enough detail to generalize the question instead of asking specifically for hardware/software solutions. However, looks like the main topic is the webOS-based smart TV, which might be an issue due to the lack of experts in the Android community. I don't know if our sister site for general computing hardware, [su] may accept this question or not.